# Gradients, Curls, and Divergence

Tags: vector-analysis

[image]

I got that d) does not make sense since (F dot G) yields a scalar and the gradient acts on a vector to yield another vector in space. So you would not be able to perform the gradient(F dot G)

Is that correct?

Comment: The gradient operator takes a smooth *scalar*-valued function as input and returns a vector-valued function as output.

Comment: @littleO: Indeed it seems clear to me that the misunderstanding here is due to not knowing that mathematicians often denote a **pointwise** operation on **functions** by the same symbol as for the operation on the **values**. I also don't see a very good reason for others to close it, since that misunderstanding explains fully the attempt given in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

No, (d) is a well-defined operation because the gradient applied to a scalar function yields a vector-valued function. You want (e). If $F,G:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then the operation $\nabla (F+G)$ is not well-defined.